# Is the count of treasury boxes and other containers predetermined per dungeon?

Tags: diablo-iii

In every dungeon there are certain boxes and other containers. Is the number of these containers fixed in every dungeon and play through?

Are there differences in each difficulty level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no set amount of magical containers in a dungeon, mind that there is a maximum though. Each dungeon is different, for example The Underbridge in act 3 (on Rakkis Crossing) contains a resplendent chest 2/3 of the time, and a treasure goblin 1/2 of the time. There will be tops 1 resplendent chest, and tops 1 treasure goblin.

These numbers vary across different dungeons, but the content of each container is determined by the difficulty: Normal will yield different items than Inferno.

It's best to experiment with your dungeon of choice, and see how much you can get out of it.

**Main message:** your mileage may vary.